# d3.js interactive grouped bar chart alternating rotation

Tags: d3.js, label, bar-chart

Using the example from http://blog.nextgenetics.net/demo/entry0032/ I wanted to try to label the grouped bar selected on mouseover as in http://bl.ocks.org/3177376.

[image]

Everything seems to work. However, the rotation only applies to the first set of bars and not the second. When I debug, the line

```
.attr("transform",
      "rotate(-90 " + x(d.date) + x1(p.key) + "," + y(d.perf) + ")");
```

seems to get skipped. I have reached my limits. Please help. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You should also add `text { pointer-events: none; }`

Comment: very simple javascript error

    x(d.date) + x1(p.key)

should be 

    (x(d.date) + x1(p.key))

and error only showed up when x(p.key) was nonzero so for the second case.

Answer (score 2):

very simple javascript error

```
x(d.date) + x1(p.key)
```

should be

```
(x(d.date) + x1(p.key))
```

a full working version can now be found at http://bl.ocks.org/3182035:

[image]